# Twisted application loses MySQL connection event with reconnect option

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

I have used twisted in a respirator IoT TCP server, and now I migrated the code to serve a connected door lock project. These two projects are running in the same cloud server, connects to the same MySQL server with two isolated MySQL accounts. However, the latter one occasionally throws an error for MySQL connection gone away.

Here is the (simplified) code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, ClientCreator
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.protocols.policies import TimeoutMixin

import txredisapi as redis

sys.path.append("..")   # Add package path, will be installed into python path later
from connector.aescrypt import aescrypt
from connector.epic_config import EpicConf

conf = EpicConf().loadConf()
dbid = string.atoi(conf['Redisdbid'])
rcs = redis.lazyConnection(password=conf['RedisPassword'], dbid=dbid, reconnect=True)
dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb",db=conf['DbName'],user=conf['DbAccount'],\
        passwd=conf['DbPassword'],host=conf['DbHost'],\
        use_unicode=True,charset=conf['DbCharset'],cp_reconnect=True)
# cp_reconnect = True is enabled.

class EpicState(object):
    pass

class AesCryptor(object):
    pass

class PlainTCP(protocol.Protocol, TimeoutMixin):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.attackFilter(data)
        self.dataDecoded(data)

    def dataDecoded(self, data):
        if "HELO" in data:
            self.onHello(data)
        else:
            print("Invalid Command")

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def onHello(self, data):
    global rcs
    self.epicstate = EpicState.HELO
    try:
        _, self.protocolVersion, self.devId = data.split(',')
    except ValueError, e:
        error = "onHello_err: {}".format(e)
        print error
        self.write(error)
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)

    if self.protocolVersion<1:
        # replace "NACK,-1"
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{},##############\r\n".format(0xFF,0xFF))

    ctx = "%s@%s"%(self.devId, self.peer.host)
    print "[dbg] isDevConnectedAlready(%s)"%(ctx)
    isConnected = yield rcs.sismember(self.factory.onlineDevices, ctx)
    print "isConnected={}".format(isConnected)

    if isConnected:
        e = "Duplicate connections"
        error = "onHello_err: {}".format(e)
        print error
        # replace "NACK,-2"
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{}\r\n".format(0xFE,0xFE))
        # Reopen for a moment
        self.devId = None
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)
    else:
        self.appendDevToDbCache(rcs)

    query = "SELECT `uid`,`deviceWriteKey`,`serverAccessKey`,`aesKey`,`aesIV`,`productId` FROM `device` WHERE `id`={} LIMIT 1".format(self.devId)
    row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
    if row:
        self.uid = row[0][0]
        self.writekey = row[0][1]
        self.serverkey = row[0][2]
        self.aes_key = row[0][3]
        self.aes_iv = row[0][4]
        self.productId = row[0][5]
        self.start = int(time.time())
        self.nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[:16]
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{}\r\n".format(self.start, self.nonce))
        self.epicstate = EpicState.IDLE
    else:
        print "Device {} No Match from DB".format(self.devId)
        self.transport.write(b"NACK\r\n") 
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    query = "SELECT `productId`, `version`,`url` FROM `firmware` WHERE `productId`={} ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1".format(self.productId)
    row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
    if row:
        self.otafile = row[0][2]
```

It is wired that if I use a Python simulator to test my server, the MySQL connection always works well, never losing connection. But if I use a physical device connecting to my server, sometimes I can see such error.

```
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 Peer: 73.202.44.233:1769 Conn+: 1:3
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 ASC[9]:HELO,1,16
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 [dbg] isDevConnectedAlready(16@73.202.44.233)
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 isConnected=False
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 [dbg] appendDevToDbCache(16@73.202.44.233)
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 Rollback failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 196, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 455, in _runInteraction
        conn.rollback()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 56, in rollback
        self._connection.rollback()
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 Rollback failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 196, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 455, in _runInteraction
        conn.rollback()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 70, in rollback
        raise ConnectionLost()
    twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionLost: 

2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 Unhandled error in Deferred:
2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 424, in errback
        self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1163, in gotResult
        _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1105, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
      File "/home/allankliu/Epic_Connector/GLINK_plus/secure_server/EpicGlinkTcpServer.py", line 414, in onHello
        row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 196, in _worker
        result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext
        return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext
        return func(*args,**kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 448, in _runInteraction
        result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 462, in _runQuery
        trans.execute(*args, **kw)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
        self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')

2018-09-25 14:21:54+0800 [DBG] devId=None, peer=None, cancel checkCommand
```

From above log file, the system throws out exceptions for

- _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
- twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionLost
- related rollback's exception for same MySQL 2006 errors.

all caused by

```
row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
```

which is used to load all meta data (AES Key/IV/Access/other keys) related to existing device from RDBS，most of them are used for later mutual authentication.

In order to capture the exceptions caused by one statement. I changed my code as following:

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def onHello(self, data):
    global rcs
    self.epicstate = EpicState.HELO
    try:
        _, self.protocolVersion, self.devId = data.split(',')
    except ValueError, e:
        error = "onHello_err: {}".format(e)
        print error
        self.write(error)
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)

    if self.protocolVersion<1:
        # replace "NACK,-1"
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{},##############\r\n".format(0xFF,0xFF))

    ctx = "%s@%s"%(self.devId, self.peer.host)
    print "[dbg] isDevConnectedAlready(%s)"%(ctx)
    isConnected = yield rcs.sismember(self.factory.onlineDevices, ctx)
    print "isConnected={}".format(isConnected)

    if isConnected:
        e = "Duplicate connections"
        error = "onHello_err: {}".format(e)
        print error
        # replace "NACK,-2"
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{}\r\n".format(0xFE,0xFE))
        # Reopen for a moment
        self.devId = None
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)
    else:
        self.appendDevToDbCache(rcs)

    query = "SELECT `uid`,`deviceWriteKey`,`serverAccessKey`,`aesKey`,`aesIV`,`productId` FROM `device` WHERE `id`={} LIMIT 1".format(self.devId)
    try:
        row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
    except:
        self.transport.write(b"MySQL error\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)

    if row:
        self.uid = row[0][0]
        self.writekey = row[0][1]
        self.serverkey = row[0][2]
        self.aes_key = row[0][3]
        self.aes_iv = row[0][4]
        self.productId = row[0][5]
        self.start = int(time.time())
        self.nonce = uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()[:16]
        self.transport.write(b"HELO,{},{}\r\n".format(self.start, self.nonce))
        self.epicstate = EpicState.IDLE
    else:
        print "Device {} No Match from DB".format(self.devId)
        self.transport.write(b"NACK\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)

    query = "SELECT `productId`, `version`,`url` FROM `firmware` WHERE `productId`={} ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1".format(self.productId)
    try:
        row = yield dbpool.runQuery(query)
    except:
        self.transport.write(b"MySQL error\r\n")
        self.transport.loseConnection()
        defer.returnValue(False)

    if row:
        self.otafile = row[0][2]
```

But I am still confused about the reconnect options for the adbapi component.

**Why it does not work as well as its previous version, in the same cloud server, same MySQL connection code ?** I have double checked with my cloud supplier, the connection has no limitation at all. Any clue to debug such issue?

**Is my try except for code good enough to capture such combined exceptions ?**